# Swift FMDB : Which method do I have to use?

Tags: swift, fmdb

I'm now studying FMDB, and there are many kinds of method 'executeQuery' and 'executeUpdate'.

```
executeQuery(sql,values:[Any])
executeQuery(sql,withArgumentsIn: [Any])
executeUpdate(sql,values:[Any])
executeUpdate(sql,withArgumentsIn: [Any])
```

I want to know a difference of these method and when I have to use which method.

Can I use any method?

I appreciate all your answers.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

**executeQuery(sql,values:[Any]) :**

This method has return type **FMResultSet**. It will give all records selected by query. We can execute **SELECT** statement using this method.

**executeUpdate :**

This method has return type **Bool**. We can execute **INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE** statements using this method.

for example

```
let sql = "insert into User(UserName,Address,Postcode) values(:username,:address,:postcode)"
let args = [“username”:”Tom”,” address”:”Newyork”,” postcode”:”123467”]
executeUpdate(sql,values:args)
```

Answer (score 0):

**executeUpdate(...)**

> executeUpdate(...) method is used for all the queries that can
>   modify the database (in other words, non Select queries)

```
database.executeUpdate("insert into test (x, y, z) values (?, ?, ?)", values: ["a", "b", "c"])
```

**executeQuery(...)**

> A SELECT statement is a query and is executed via one of the
>   -executeQuery... methods.

```
database.executeQuery("select x, y, z from test", values: nil)
```

[FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

Comment: is there any difference in executeUpdate(sql,values:[Any]) and
executeUpdate(sql,withArgumentsIn: [Any])??
can I use anything?

Comment: You can see definition in `FMDatabase.h` class by jump to definition, it's about throwing `Error`

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the difference by looking at the function signature.

```
executeQuery(sql: String, withArgumentsIn: [Any]) -> FMResultSet?
executeQuery(sql: String, values: [Any]?) throws -> FMResultSet
```

`executeQuery` returns a `FMResultSet`, so it's for statements that return data (i.e. SELECT statements).  The difference between the two versions is in what happens when the query fails - the first version returns nil on a failure, while the second throws an error.

```
executeUpdate(sql: String, withArgumentsIn: [Any]) -> Bool
executeUpdate(sql: String, values: [Any]?) throws -> Void
```

`executeUpdate` doesn't return data; it's used for basically everything else.  Like before, the difference between the two is how they handle failure - the first returns a boolean (true if the statement succeeds, false if it fails), while the second doesn't return anything but throws an error if it fails instead.